# .htaccess RewriteRule for change the path if a word appears in the path

Tags: mod-rewrite

:-)

I need a .htaccess RewriteRule that can do this:

If the browser load this url path:

```
http://www.domain.com/example/word_to_change/
```

change to

```
http://www.domain.com/example/new_word/
```

take a look that the "word_to_change" and "new_word" appears in the third level in the path

I was tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(word_to_change/)?$ /new_word/ [R,L]
```

But only works if the "word_to_change" appears in the second level, not in the third.

thanks for your help! :)

---

ADDED:

three examples:
need to change

```
http://www.domain.com/second_level_with_any_word/specific_word_1 or
http://www.domain.com/example_1/specific_word_1 or
http://www.domain.com/example_2/specific_word_1
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/second_level_anything/specific_word_2 or
http://www.domain.com/example_1/specific_word_2 or
http://www.domain.com/example_2/specific_word_2
```

maybe is mor simple for explain with this other example:

```
http://*/*/specific_word1
for
http://*/*/specific_word2
```

Comment: please explain what is second and third levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what to acomplish, if you want to change ANY word that apeaers after example with a SPECIFIC word then what you need is:

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*) /new_path/ [R,L]
```

if you want to pass that word as a paramater you can use

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.*) /new_path/process.php?word=$1 [R,L]
```

if you want to send any URL that ends with a specific word try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/old_word/$ /$1/new_word/ [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Eyal, yes, I need to change a specific word for other specific word.

Comment: I was added other example. I was tried you first rule, but still happen the same situation, only works if the "specific_word_for_change" is in the second level, like http://www.domain.com/specific_word_for_change", but don't works if is here: http://www.domain.com/anypath/specific_word_for_change thanks for your help :)

Comment: so what you are saying you want a rule for any URL that ENDS with a specific word correct?

Comment: yes, correct, sorry for my bad explanation and my bad english.

Comment: i made an update to the answer check it out hopefuly it works for you

Comment: don't work for me, but maybe is something related with the server because use litespeed instead of apache, but I think that your reply is good and maybe I need to try some other things around your last rewrite, thanks for your time :)